# Website width is always larger than the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I recently published a site and I realize that the size of each page of this site is always wider than the size of the screen (Even if my screen has a resolution of 3840 * 2160!) .

I use Boostrap 4 and in the _Layout view, I have by default the meta tag which allows to adapt the size of the page to the used device:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I did not touch the bootstrap.css file (at least nothing who's related to the size).

I noticed that if in the _Layout view I remove all  which form the top of my page (my menu), the width of the page is correct (but it is obviously not a solution).

So I have a removed one div class each per each to see which one provided the problem but no way, each time the width is always greater than the page.

Do you have an idea?

```
<div class="bs-docs-section clearfix">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="bs-component">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:#C6DA4B">
                    <div class="container p-0"> 
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                           //code
                        </div>
                            <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

With row `m-0`, it show like that

[image]

Comment: give `margin: 0;` first to `row` class or `m-0`

Comment: @NishargShah Now it is not wider but a have some blank space on left and right of the top menu.

Comment: can you provide image of that ?

Comment: `row` inside `container`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't get it since i do not have a row inside of my container (in this page). Are you suggesting me to add a div class row just inside of my container?

Comment: there is a row without container at the start of your code

Comment: I've tried it but the problem is that the top menu background does not take the whole width of the page now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `margin: 0;` first to `row` class or `m-0`, so it not be wider or remove horizontal bar from your page.

for full width add class `padding: 0;` or `p-0` in your `container` class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="bs-docs-section">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-lg-12 p-0">
            <div class="bs-component">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:#C6DA4B">
                    <div class="container p-0"> 
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                           //code
                        </div>
                        <partial name="_LoginPartial">
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i've just tried <div class"row m-0 p-0"> but the result is the same as just m-0

Comment: Yup, i've edited my initial post with the actual code. I also tried to put the container as the first div but if i do that my top menu is not taking the whole widgth of the page.

Comment: Aaaaand, it works now! Had to add p-0 after col-lg-12! Thx bro

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about bootstrap, but it seems like you need another "container" div around your "row".

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      [etc]
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap row has a default left and right margin with -15px that's why the page shows horizontal scroll bar. To fix this we have a container wrapped to the row like .container or container-fluid (Depends according to the layout).